# Java 8 - The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Developer,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Developer>)

Tags: java, spring, option-type

I'm starting into java development using spring framework, and for the purpose of getting something a little more complex than a hello world I found this tutorial and tried to follow.

https://www.toptal.com/spring/beginners-guide-to-mvc-with-spring-framework

The issue i'm finding is that, the proposed code: Inside the DevelopersController.java is getting errors in eclipse due to the fact that my my classes that extends "CrudRepository" return a Optional < Skill> and Optional < Developer> instead of just a Skill/Developer object.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/developer/{id}/skills", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String developersAddSkill(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Long skillId, Model model) {
    Skill skill = skillRepository.findOne(skillId);
    Developer developer = repository.findOne(id);

    if (developer != null) {
        if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.getSkills().add(skill);
        }
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", repository.findOne(id));
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }

    model.addAttribute("developers", repository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/developers";
}
```

I looked for some information on Java 8 Optional but since I still lack coding experience I having a hard time undestanding how to use it properly.

I changed the code to and managed to get one of the errors out....

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/developer/{id}/skills", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String developersAddSkill(
        @PathVariable Long id, 
        @RequestParam Long skillId, 
        Model model) {
    Optional<Skill> skill = skillRepository.findById(skillId);
    Optional<Developer> developer = repository.findById(id);

    developer.get().getSkills();
    if (developer != null) {
        if (!developer.get().hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.get().getSkills().add(skill);
        }
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", repository.findById(id));
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }
    return "Confused";
}
```

But i'm still getting the errors bellow in my eclipse:

- The method add(Skill) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Optional)
- The method getId() is undefined for the type Optional
- The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (Optional)

How can i fix this?
Also Why does the line:

```
if (!developer.get().hasSkill(skill)) {
```

shows no errors, but the line:

```
developer.get().getSkills().add(skill);
```

does?

Comment: Why don't you try like this:

    Optional<Developer> optionalDeveloper = repository.findById(id);
    Developer developer = optionalDeveloper.get();
    if (developer != null) {
        if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.getSkills().add(skill);
        }
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", repository.findOne(id));
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [changelog](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/changelog.txt), newer versions of spring-data (1.6.0 above) will return Optional for findById() methods. In previous versions of spring-data the result of findById() would be `null` if an object with the specified id isn't found in the database.

As shown in your example, an `Optional` may contain some developer or no developer. To check if findById() have returned a developer you should use:

```
//You probably should rename the developer variable to "result".
Optional<Developer> developer = repository.findById(id);
if(developer.isPresent()){
    //developer found, you can get it.
    Developer aDeveloper = developer.get();
    //aDeveloper.hasSkill(skill); is acessible now.
}else{
    //no developer found with the specified Id.
}
```

In previous versions of spring-boot with spring-data dependecy lower than 1.6.x you would use:

```
Developer developer = repository.findById(id);
if (developer != null) {
    //developer found       
}
```

If you try developer.get() when there is no developer there, an Exception will be thrown. So, check with isPresent() first.

Comment: With Java 9, it's usually preferable to go with `isPresentOrElse` instead of using an `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

This line `developer.get().getSkills().add(skill);` is wrong. You are trying to add an Optional to a List of type `Skill`.

To fix this error you have to change it to `developer.get().getSkills().add(skill.get());`.

Also, never put business logic in the controller. Always use a service class for that.

Service classes are where you put your business logic. Controller is where you link business logic with front end.

Comment: Now i managed to understand the answer, thank you for it

When you say i should use a service class for my business logic, do you have a suggestion how could I do that in this case?

Comment: Follow MVC pattern. Spring MVC has fully support for this. Your each layer has responsibilities and the should not do anything another than their responsibilities. Controller should should link UI and business logic. Service classes perform business logic(where you put your if, else conditions). Repositories should use to save your domain objects. So create a separate class and move logic inside the addDevelopersSkills to that class( or any other logic related to Developer).  You can find relevant annotations for these like Controller, Service, Repository.