# Spring boot: How to handle the method hasSkill(Skill) in the type Developer is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Skill>)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am starting to learn the Spring boot framework, especially for developing an application under the MVC concept with Spring Boot. I found an article and tried to re-implement:

https://www.toptal.com/spring/beginners-guide-to-mvc-with-spring-framework

I used Java 8, Spring Boot 2.5.1, and Gradle. During the implementation, I got several errors especially in this section:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/developer/{id}/skills", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String developersAddSkill(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Long skillId, Model model) {
    Skill skill = skillRepository.findOne(skillId);
    Developer developer = repository.findOne(id);

    if (developer != null) {
        if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.getSkills().add(skill);
        }
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", repository.findOne(id));
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }

    model.addAttribute("developers", repository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/developers";
}
```

I am a new learner of Spring Boot and Java. The problem like similar to the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316923/java-8-the-method-saves-in-the-type-crudrepositorydeveloper-long-is-not-ap).
I modified the code by following the Eclipse recommendation and discussion in the previous post.
This is my new code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/developer/{id}/skills", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String developersAddSkill(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Long skillId, Model model) {
    
    Optional<Skill> skill = skillRepository.findById(skillId);
    Optional<Developer> optionalDeveloper = repository.findById(id);
    Developer developer = optionalDeveloper.get();

    if (developer != null) {
        if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.getSkills().add(skill.get());
        }
        
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", repository.findById(id));
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }

    model.addAttribute("developers", repository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/developers";
}
```

However, there is still one error:

`The method hasSkill(Skill) in the type Developer is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Skill>`

I tried to fix it, but I am still cannot do it.
How can I fix this problem? Could everyone suggest the solution? I would appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. You are passing Optional varibale inside the method when it actually expects skill object.

Modified code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/developer/{id}/skills", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String developersAddSkill(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam Long skillId, Model model) {
    
    Optional<Skill> optionalSkill = skillRepository.findById(skillId);
    Optional<Developer> optionalDeveloper = repository.findById(id);
    

    if (optionalDeveloper.isPresent() && optionalSkill.isPresent()) {

        Developer developer = optionalDeveloper.get();
        Skill skill = optionalSkill.get();

        if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
            developer.getSkills().add(skill);
        }
        
        repository.save(developer);
        model.addAttribute("developer", developer);
        model.addAttribute("skills", skillRepository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/developer/" + developer.getId();
    }

    model.addAttribute("developers", repository.findAll());
    return "redirect:/developers";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. You are doing

   ```
   Developer developer = optionalDeveloper.get();

   if (developer != null) {
    ...
   ```

without checking if the Optional<Developer> is present.
If the Optional is not present (represents the absence of a value),
then this will throw a NoSuchElementException - it will not return null.

So, this should be:

```
if(optionalDeveloper.isPresent()) {
  ...
```

2. You have

```
if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
   developer.getSkills().add(skill);
}
```

but developer.hasSkill() takes a Skill as an argument - you are passing an Optional.

So, this should be:

```
if(optionalSkill.isPresent()) {
  final Skill skill = optionalSkill.get());
  if (!developer.hasSkill(skill)) {
   developer.getSkills().add(skill);
  }
}
```